# Javascript: how to get from textaeria filled with dots and stars get 0-1 array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, text-manipulation

I want to create a simple javascript "life game" implementation. I want user to be capable of inputing his structures..

So we have a textaeria, user fills it with something like

```
*···
*·*·
**··
```

How to get from such input width `4` , height `3`, and an array field with

```
100010101100
```

How to do get such data from text input via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So character 183 rather than a period?

```
var s = document.getElementById(..);
//remove all whitespace, replace *, replace ·
s = s.replace(/\s+/gm, "").replace(/\*/g, "1").replace(/\xb7/g, "0");
```

If a period use `\`. instead of `\xb7`

Its not clear but if you want that as an array stick `.split("");` on the end.

Edit for width/height

```
var width =  (s + "\r\n").indexOf("\r\n"); //position of 1st new line
var height =  s.split("\r\n").length; //count of lines
```

Comment: but how to get Width and Height values?

Comment: I actually wanted result in form of var array = new array(width* height); than filed with ones and 0s

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to split each row to an array, then loop through the resulting array, loop through each char on the string located on that index, check if its a * and add a 1 to the result string or 0 for . to the result string and wham, you'll get your result.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery to create 1 string:

```
$("#test").val().replace(/·/g,'0').replace(/\*/g,'1').replace(/\n\r?/g,'');
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pBauP/

another example to create an array of rows containing an array of cells, is that what you want with width and height?

```
var results = [];

var arr = $("#test").val().split('\n');

$.each(arr, function() {
var row = this.replace(/·/g,'0').replace(/\*/g,'1').split("");
results.push(row);
});
```

demo2: http://jsfiddle.net/3qqkY/

Comment: but how to get Width and Height values?)

Comment: i don't really understand what you want with the width and height?

Comment: Width  and  Height  of inputed by user matrix

Comment: updated the answer creating an array of (width*height) called results